# Android ViewModel's LiveData not updating the UI

Tags: java, android

I have the following fragment:

todays_training_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.myapp.viewmodel.CurrentTrainingSessionViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.CurrentProgramFragment"
        android:id="@+id/todays_training_fragment"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewmodel.activeProgramId)}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

TodaysTrainingFragment.java

```
public class TodaysTrainingFragment extends Fragment {
    CurrentTrainingSessionViewModel viewModel;
    private TodaysTrainingFragmentBinding binding;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(inflater, R.layout.todays_training_fragment, container, false);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        viewModel =
                ViewModelProviders
                        .of(this)
                        .get(CurrentTrainingSessionViewModel.class);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding.setViewmodel(viewModel);

        binding.getViewmodel().setActiveProgramId(12342); // <-- I'm expecting the layout to show this value
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    }
}
```

CurrentTrainingSessionViewModel.java

```
public class CurrentTrainingSessionViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<Long> activeProgramId = new MutableLiveData<>(0L);



    public long getActiveProgramId() {
        return activeProgramId.getValue();
    }

    public void setActiveProgramId(long id) {
        activeProgramId.postValue(id);
    }

}
```

I'm expecting my layout to show 0 in the text view as it's the initial value of activeProgramId, and then update the displayed value to 12342 when it's subsequently changed. However, the value stays 0 and doesn't get updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try, as the last line `binding.executePendingBindings()`, you are manually setting data and not from some oberver pattern like `MutableLiveData` you may need to manually tell the binding something has changed.

Comment: I found that if I return the MutableLiveData from my getter in the view model, instead of its `getValue`, the UI correctly gets updated. So it seems the solution is to return the MutableLiveData object instead of its Long value. Is there any issues with exposing the MutableLiveData object directly? Or is it the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you do this twice: binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
Resetting it straight after updating the LiveData in ViewModel may be the culprit, so try removing it from onViewCreated.

Another thing to try is inflating the Databinding without using DataBindingUtil, try this: TodaysTrainingFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater)

Comment: that didn't fix it. The layout is already able to access that value through its getter

Comment: I've changed the answer, give that a shot.

Comment: Apparently the issue is that I need to return MutableLiveData from my view model, and not the long value obtained from calling getValue(). If I return the MutableLiveData object, the UI gets correctly updated. Is there anything wrong with doing this I should know about?

Comment: That's it, I didn't notice, well done you answered your own question! We setLifecycleOwner on the binding so that it will Observe the MutableLiveData. You'd be safer to pass an immutable LiveData outside of the ViewModel though to avoid unwanted changes. Have getActiveProgramId return LiveData<Long> to achieve that.